# Similar components with multiple data in one vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, element-ui

Basically Similar components for one page but individual data populate and components from [Element-UI](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select)

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      options: [{
          value: 'Option1',
          label: 'Option1',
        },

        {
          value: 'Option2',
          label: 'Option2',
        },
        {
          value: 'Option3',
          label: 'Option3',
        },
      ],
      value: '',
      optionss: [{
          values: 'bKash',
          label: 'bKash',
        },

        {
          values: 'Rocket',
          label: 'Rocket',
        },
        {
          values: 'Bank A/C',
          label: 'Bank A/C',
        },
      ],
      values: '',
    }
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.11.1/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.11.1/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    
    <div>
       <el-select v-model="value" placeholder="Select Account">
              <el-option
                      v-for="item in options"
                      :key="item.value"
                      :label="item.label"
                      :value="item.value">
              </el-option>
</el-select>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    
  <div>
    <el-select v-model="values" placeholder="Select Account">
              <el-option
                      v-for="item in optionss"
                      :key="item.values"
                      :label="item.label"
                      :values="item.values">
              </el-option>
 </el-select>
    
    
    
    
    
  </div>
 
</template>
</div>
```

One component works fine but other components on select not work, but data populated correctly, Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the msg error is clear you miss value in the second component, you write `:values` instead of `:value`  inside `el-option`, but label is fine, so the component can populate the labels but not the values.

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      options: [{
          value: 'Option1',
          label: 'Option1',
        },

        {
          value: 'Option2',
          label: 'Option2',
        },
        {
          value: 'Option3',
          label: 'Option3',
        },
      ],
      value: '',
      optionss: [{
          value: 'bKash',
          label: 'bKash',
        },

        {
          value: 'Rocket',
          label: 'Rocket',
        },
        {
          value: 'Bank A/C',
          label: 'Bank A/C',
        },
      ],
      values: '',
    }
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.11.1/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.11.1/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    
    <div>
       <el-select v-model="value" placeholder="Select Account">
              <el-option
                      v-for="item in options"
                      :key="item.value"
                      :label="item.label"
                      :value="item.value">
              </el-option>
</el-select>
value= {{value}}
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    
  <div>
    <el-select v-model="values" placeholder="Select Account">
              <el-option
                      v-for="item in optionss"
                      :key="item.values"
                      :label="item.label"
                      :value="item.value"> <!-- here was the error -->
              </el-option>
 </el-select>

values = {{values}}
    
    
    
    
    
  </div>
 
</template>
</div>
```

Comment: If you see my data populates correctly but on select, the second one will not select and not showing